# How to limit contacts imported through Live SDK

Tags: rest, live-sdk

Can we Set a limit on the number of contats returned by Live SDK?

https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts?access_token=xccxxxx';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `limit` parameter with the number of the results you want.

So to limit the results to 5 in your example that would be:

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts?limit=5&access_token=xccxxxx
```

Comment: cant believe i didnt try that.. but couldnt find that in microsoft aouth documentation either. Thanks